# Wikitude app crash (poi adding issue) in iPhone 4.0

Tags: ios4

I am currently working in iPhone augmentation reality application in which  I have added poi over camera view, but my application is crash and it's throwing an exception (CALayer NAN 15).

Following is the code that I am using.

```
wikitudeAR = [[WikitudeARViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self applicationPackage:nil applicationKey:nil; applicationName:nil developerName:nil];     

- (void) verificationDidSucceed {

id appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UIWindow *window = [appDelegate window];    
[window addSubview:[wikitudeAR start];
}
- (void) verificationDidFail {

}

- (void) didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation*) newLocation
            fromLocation: (CLLocation*) oldLocation {

}
-(void) APIFinishedLoading
{       //arr is  current location data
NSMutableArray *addPOIData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<[arr  count];i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict= [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    WTPoi* poi = [[WTPoi alloc] initWithName:currentMapLocation.locationTitle AndLatitude:[[dict objectforKey:@"lat"]doubleValue]AndLongitude:[[dict        objectforKey:@"long"]doubleValue]];
    poi.icon = @"http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/9931/parking.png";
poi.shortDescription = @"Open Monday to Friday 6:30 to 7pm. Tariff plan range from £5";
poi.thumbnail = @"http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/9931/parking.png";
    [addPOIData addObject: poi];
    [poi release];
}
    [[WikitudeARViewController sharedInstance] addPOIs: addPOIData];
[addPOIData release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the new version of the Wikitude iPhone API which should fix the described issue. You can download it from http://www.wikitude.org/developers

Cheers, Nicolas